# Modifying the values in matrices

Tags: python, arrays, list, for-loop, matrix

I want to modify the value of 4 to 19. 
I want to understand how I could do this using for loops and indexes. (I've seen a lot of numpy examples but I want to learn through using for loops)

```
matrix = [[1, 2, 3],
          [4, 5, 6],
          [7, 8, 9]]

for i in range(len(matrix)):
    for j in range(len(matrix[i])):
"insert code here..."
```

Comment: A for loop wouldn't be optimal here. Is there a reason why you want to use a for loop specifically?

Comment: `matrix[1][0] = 19`

Comment: @NicolasGervais It's one of the ways i understand how to use matrices, is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in range(len(matrix)):
    for j in range(len(matrix[i])):
        if matrix[i][j] == 4:
            matrix[i][j] = 19
```